# Could this be a hardware issue?

Tags: boot

I am new with Ubuntu it seems to me like a great option to get over Windows. I have never used it though so I am completely lost. I had Windows 7 64 bit installed on my desktop, (It has a AMD Phoenom II X4 945, ASUS M4A89GTD PRO (No USB 3.0), 4 gb ram DDR3, 500 HDD). A disk with Ubuntu 12.something was given to me to install it and I did but then I was told to upgrade to 14.04 the latest version and the system did not recognize my password. Then we tried with a disc 14.01 but it just do not work. Then I put a new hdd in but now even though when it accepts the hdd I have the following error:

"Reboot and select proper Boot device or insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key"

Then if a press a key I have the same error again. The boot order that I have is:
CD
HDD
USB

I hope you can help me folks, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your Ubuntu boot media is not set up correctly, and even though your computer is trying to boot from the disc it can't. If you have a Windows computer on hand, I would grab a fresh copy of the Ubuntu 14.04.1 Desktop .iso from [the website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/) and then install [Linux Live USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download) to create a bootable Ubuntu thumb drive. Alternatively, you can just burn the new .iso file to a DVD, but I like Linux Live USB Creator because it verifies the integrity of the disc image for you. If you do choose to burn the new disc image to a DVD, make sure you check the hash and compare it to the list [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes).

Another minor note would be to grab the 64-bit .iso because your computer is capable of running it.

Comment: Thank you Arnon I will try that and I will ping you with results. I do appreciate the time you take to help me.

Comment: Hey Arnon you solve my problem my friend, now I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my desktop. Thank you once again. I will keep reading the forum to find answers to my future questions. To have check this site was the best idea, again thank you!!!

Comment: Glad to be able to help.